# Can't Get Current User Certificate From X.509 Store

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I am Developing Asp.net application in Which I Want to Read Current user Certificate From x509Store...Its Working Fine For my Local Machine .. When I Deploy application on IIS...than I Can't Pick Current user Certificate which I will Use for application authentication...

This Is Following Code for Working Fine for Local System..

```
public  X509Certificate2 selectCert(StoreName store, StoreLocation Location ,  string windowTitle, string windowMsg)
    {

        X509Certificate2 certSelected = null;
        X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(store);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        X509Certificate2Collection col = x509Store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, windowTitle, windowMsg, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

        if (sel.Count > 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2Enumerator en = sel.GetEnumerator();
            en.MoveNext();
            certSelected = en.Current;
        }

        x509Store.Close();

        return certSelected;
    }
```

Here  x509Store.Certificates Return Some Collection of Current User Certificate..
But when I Run Deployed application In ISS. x509Store.Certificates Give Empty Collection at Sever...For Current User & I've checked my personal store (via certmgr.mmc) and I'm sure that I have the certificates...Crucial Problem Please Solve Out...I can't Understand .. What is happened...

Thanx

Comment: Under what user you are running IIS and where you have deployed certificate (is this same user)?

Comment: I need all Browser Certificate for Current User...which are store in x509 Certificate Store...In  Personal Tab..N i deploy application at local iis..which have same user...

Comment: As explained by Gusman in another answer, your are running the IIS under account which has no CurrentUser store. However, ask yourself why you need that store. You can put all needed certificates to LocalMachine store and it's accessible for the IIS server.

Answer (score 2):

Your IIS app must be running under the ASP .net built in account in IIS, which does not have permission to access the certificate stores.

One way to solve it is to change the user to some other wihch has permissions, but it will lead to security issues.

A better approach but more complex is to have a service executed with elevated privileges which accepts incomming TCP/UDP/pipes connections from local machine, retrieves the certificates and pass them out, in this way you can call safely that service from your asp.net page without giving it elevated permissions

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the certificate as CurrentUser, only services running under your username will have access.
In order to access the certificate for all usernames in a machine, you will have to install the certificate as LocalMachine and retrieve the same using LocalMachine

for more info [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548653(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: my application is hosted on server ...if i will use Local Machine then then it gives the Certificate of Server ...I need that every user have a Client Certificate provided by me .. only Access the Application